# Wordpress - Some child theme files are not recognized in the template

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, themes, children, wordpress-shortcode

I'm new to template designs and I'm trying out altering some things in the parent theme from the child theme.
My problem is that there are some files that are not recognized, for example the style.css from the child theme does work for me, but there are other files that I need to load in the child theme instead of the parent theme that I am not able to get them to work.

I am trying to get the `/inc/core/shortcodes.php` file recognized in the child theme, as there is an html `<h4>` tag that I want to replace with an `<h3>`.

The file structure is as follows:

[image]

Any help would be appreciated, best regards.

Answer (score 0):

Child theme implementation isn't a universal thing in WordPress - each theme implements it in its own way (some very poorly), and not everything is necessarily overwritable through a child theme. Usually, only actual template files are overwritable. The specific file you're referencing (`shortcodes.php`) likely contains shortcodes added by the theme, not template data, so wouldn't generally be overwritable in that way.

The better way to handle what I suspect you're trying to accomplish (modifying how a specific shortcode works) would either be to use hooks in the shortcode (assuming the developer added them) to manipulate the shortcode output, or copy the shortcode(s) you want to modify into a file in your child theme, change the name (and function name) of the shortcode, and load it from the `functions.php` file. This also gets more complicated if you're using a theme with a page builder (Gutenberg, Visual Composer, Elementor, Cornerstone, Avia, Avada, Beaver Builder, etc). Most page builders use some form of shortcode under the hood to actually generate the displayed data. If your theme uses a page builder like this, and the shortcode in question has a corresponding element in the page builder, you'll also have to add a button for your modified version (or insert is using the "HTML" or "Code" element) to actually use it - the existing button wouldn't incorporate your changed code. All of the page builders mentioned above can be (and have been) extended in this way.